# Does anyone have an example of enterprise library 6 exception handling using Microsoft MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library-6

I need to build an example using this technology for a job evaluation in a project I'm working but I cant find much information to build the example and for the evaluation, anyone?

Comment: Don't go this path, is a dead end. Try other alternatives... I have found that implementing a filter you can capture all exceptions or try to use serilog, elmah.io or other alternative with better options and flexibility....